# .click function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have JavaScript for a commenting system, however when I click on the submit button with the class name "com_submit" nothing happens except the page reloads. Even if I leave the form empty and submit the alert should pop up but it isn't. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
$(function() {

$('.com_submit').live("click", function() {
    var comment = $("#comment").val();
    var user_id = $("#user_id").val();
    var perma_id = $("#perma_id").val();
    var dataString = 'comment='+ comment + '&user_id='+ user_id + '&perma_id=' + $perma_id;
    if(comment=='') {
        alert('Please Give Valid Details');
    }
    else {
        $("#flash").show();
        $("#flash").fadeIn(400).html('<img src="ajax-loader.gif" />Loading Comment...');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "commentajax.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function(html){
                $("ol#update").append(html);
                $("ol#update li:first").fadeIn("slow");
                $("#flash").hide();
            }
        });
    }
    return false;
});
});
```

I have tried using .click, .live and .bind none of these work

Comment: Can you also provide the button declaration?

Comment: Yes the button is: `<input type="submit" class="com_submit" value=" Submit Comment " />`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a typo in your code because of which runtime error occurs and page reloads since it is a link.

```
var perma_id = $("#perma_id").val();


$(function() {

$('.com_submit').live("click", function() {
    var comment = $("#comment").val();
    var user_id = $("#user_id").val();
    var perma_id = $("#perma_id").val();
    var dataString = 'comment='+ comment + '&user_id='+ user_id + '&perma_id=' 
     + perma_id;//<<<------ Here was the typo(You have used $perma_id)
    if(comment=='') {
        alert('Please Give Valid Details');
    }
    else {
        $("#flash").show();
        $("#flash").fadeIn(400).html('<img src="ajax-loader.gif" />Loading Comment...');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "commentajax.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function(html){
                $("ol#update").append(html);
                $("ol#update li:first").fadeIn("slow");
                $("#flash").hide();
            }
        });
    }
    return false;
});
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I can't believe I missed that. That fixed the problem

Answer (score 0):

That's working as expected. In other words, your submit button is submitting. What you want to do is stop the normal behavior. Try this:

```
$('.com_submit').live("click", function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
.
.
.
```

At the top of your code.